# Выскакивает ошибка Traceback (most recent call last): a = input() EOFError: EOF when reading a line make: *** [run] Error 1

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
n = int(input())

correct = 0

flag = False

while n > 0:
    a = input()
    
    if ("раз" == a) or ("два" == a) or ("три" == a) or ("четыре" == a):
        correct += 1
        flag = True

    elif ("раз" != a) or ("два" != a) or ("три" != a) or ("четыре" != a):
        print(f"Правильных отсчётов было {correct}, но теперь вы ошиблись.")
        correct = 0
        n -= 1

    if n == 0:
        flag = False


if flag:
    print("На сегодня хватит.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Код рабочий, когда именно у вас ошибка то возникает?

Кстати можно писать проще:

```
if a in ("раз", "два", "три", "четыре"):
    correct += 1
    flag = True
else:
    print(f"Правильных отсчётов было {correct}, но теперь вы ошиблись.")
    correct = 0
    n -= 1
```

кроме того проверка

```
("раз" != a) or ("два" != a) or ("три" != a) or ("четыре" != a):
```

будет работать всегда (всегда будет истинной) - так что ошибка использовать такие конструкции

а поскольку

```
while n > 0:

    if n == 0:
        flag = False
```

то после выхода из цикла flag всегда будет False и

```
if flag:
    print("На сегодня хватит.")
```

никогда срабатывать не будет

Comment: Вот именно, что он рабочий но система дает такую ошибку при проверке                                                      Ввод
2
раз
два
три
четыре
раз
двыа
раз
два
три
три Ожидаемый результат
Правильных отсчётов было 5, но теперь вы ошиблись.
Правильных отсчётов было 3, но теперь вы ошиблись.
На сегодня хватит. Вывод
Правильных отсчётов было 5, но теперь вы ошиблись.
Makefile:5: recipe for target 'run' failed

Answer (score 0):

Не надо делать `elif`, сделайте `else`. Ведь в `if` у нас и так условие ИЛИ (`or`), и если оно не выполняется, то по любому значение `a` не равно ***НИКАКОМУ*** ИЗ ВАРИАНТОВ.

Вот новый код:

```
n = int(input())

correct = 0

flag = False

while n > 0:
    a = input()

    if "раз" == a or "два" == a or "три" == a or "четыре" == a:
        correct += 1
        flag = True

    else:
        print("Правильных отсчётов было "+str(correct)+", но теперь вы ошиблись.")
        correct = 0
        n -= 1

    


print("На сегодня хватит. Вы исчерпали все попытки!")
```

Если я правильно понял, что вам нужно)